# How do you define the types of dependent variables in typescirpt ？

Tags: typescript

Should must I do ?

This is my implementation, but it's wrong

```
interface FnParams<T extends 'a'|'b' = 'a'> {
   mode: T
   onChange: (value: T extends 'a' ? string : number) => void
}
const fn = ({ mode, onChange }: FnParams) => {
   if (mode === 'a') {
      onChange('string')
   }
   if (mode === 'b') { // error
      onChange(123) // error
   }
}
fn({
   mode: 'b', // error
   onChange: value => value
})
```

I expect
mode = 'a', The value of type is string
mode = 'b', The value of type is number

Comment: You probably want `FnParams` to be a union and not a generic; or if it is a generic, you want it to distribute over its input type.  Both approaches are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WkkBlW).  Do either of those work for you? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz Do you know why [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvGjQw) is not working? The conditional type is not being evaluated.

Comment: Generic types are not narrowed by control flow analysis, so the check `if (mode === 'a')` does nothing to the type `T` itself; see [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for a feature request which might change that.  But this seems like a followup question, which is out of scope. Let's focus on your original question as asked, and if you have further questions you could create a new post.

Comment: Assuming you're asking "what must I do" or "what should I do", then my suggestion is [either of these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/WkkBlW). Does that work or am I missing something about your question?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you very much. I want FnParams to be a generic.`DistribuiveGenericObject`
But, why are `onChange('string')`  and `onChange(123)` wrong in Typescriptv4.5.2?
Error message: 
`TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`
`TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

Comment: Because [support for destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) was added in TypeScript 4.6.  It feels like you're only engaging here to ask followup questions, so I'm not sure how or if to proceed.  Maybe I will write up an answer explaining the `DistributiveGenericObject` solution, but I'm concerned that more questions will be forthcoming in the comments.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for helping me with my confusion, there is no more